# ng-animate child element inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to animate a child element inside a ng-repeat.
This is what I have now. I am using css to animate but if you know a different better method please tell.

index.html

```
<div class="container slider" ng-controller="sliderCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="slide in slides" class="slide" ng-include="'/partials/slider/' + slide.image + '.html'">
        </div>
</div>
```

01.html (included inside ng-repeat)

```
<div class="slider-message-1">
    <span>message</span>
</div>

<img class="slide-image" ng-src="assets/img/img00.jpg" />
```

sass file

```
.slide{

    &.ng-hide{

        .slider-message-1{
            display: block!important;
            visibility: hidden;
        }
    }

    &.ng-hide-remove {

        .slider-message-1{
            animation: fadeIn 2s;
            -webkit-animation: fadeIn 2s;
        }
    }

    &.ng-hide-add {

        .slider-message-1{
            -webkit-animation: fadeOut 1s;
            animation: fadeOut 1s;
            visibility: visible;
        }
    }
}
```